# Android Live TV new values resource directory for languages are not working

Tags: android, locale, android-source, android-tv

the requirement of my project is to add the support of **Welsh (cy)** language in Android Live TV app. I have created a **values-cy** directory and put a placeholder file for Welsh language. But these resources are not building in Android TV open source project. If anyone know please help to sort this issue.

Comment: Is it _Welsh(United Kingdom)_ ?

Comment: Yes. My locale is cy_GB. but according to Android doc it should pick strings values from values-cy file.

Comment: Have you tried with _values-cy-rGB_?

Comment: Yes I have tried, but no luck. I am building Android Live TV from android open source using mk file.

Comment: For a simple android app it was working fine.